# How can i disable medical term spell check in textarea but i need to check spelling and grammar

Tags: html

here is my code :

```
<textarea name="doctornotes" id="doctornotes" cols="80" rows="10" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
```

in this text area i am entering below text :

```
This is a medicine name : CROCIN TABS
```

here `CROCIN` is medical term and red line is coming and i don't want red line below my text if it is medical terms.

Comment: Either set [`spellcheck="false"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-spellcheck) or add `CROCIN` to your browser's dictionary.

Comment: I didn't find a "real" solution either. I would also disable spellchecking and see if there is a good javascript solution or so. http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The [`spellcheck`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#spelling-and-grammar-checking) attribute is vaguely defined, and there is no way to specify which kind of spelling checks are to be performed (and probably won’t be anytime soon). Currently, browsers that support `spellcheck` use fairly simple spelling checkers, which might be user-customizable, but not author-customizable.

Here’s a possible scenario for a workaround: Use `<div contenteditable>` instead of `<textarea>` (so that the content can contain markup), and add event handlers that react to user input and process check whether the word entered is in your list of terms, and if it is, wrap it inside `<span spellcheck=false>`.